# Time Interval Task Service

Tags: c#

How can i change DaysInterval to 12 hrs or something rather than days.
In this code:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            // Create a new task definition and assign properties
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

            // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
            td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 1 });

            // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

            // Register the task in the root folder
            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

            // Remove the task we just created
            ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check TaskScheduler Codeplex site?

There is a detailed explanation of triggers

> http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TriggerSamples&referringTitle=Documentation